# Not able to find start of 53rd week using method Date.commercial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, week-number

`Date.commercial` method to find start of week (Monday) is not working for 53rd week

```
Date.commercial(2018, 1, 1)
#=> 2018-01-01
Date.commercial(2018, 52, 1)
#=> 2018-12-24
```

It throws error when I try to find Monday of 53rd week in years which has 53 weeks.

```
Date.commercial(2018, 53, 1)
# ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Also, its definition is also not clear to me. Like how these two are behaving so differently:

```
Date.commercial(2015, 1, 1)
#=> 2014-12-29

Date.commercial(2016, 1, 1)
#=> 2016-01-04
```

I think its because definition of `Date.commercial()` to convert week number to date is different from that of `Date.strftime("%W")`. Is there any method which can convert year's week number to Monday date of the week consistent with `Date.strftime("%W")`, i.e. reverse function of `Date.strftime("%W")`?

Comment: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2018 has a nice table showing the commercial weeks. As you can see, there's no week 53 in 2018. The day after week 52 (2018-12-31) already belongs to commercial week 01, 2019 (that's how it is defined).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any method which can convert year's week number to Monday date of the week consistent with `Date.strftime("%W")`, i.e. reverse function of `Date.strftime("%W")`?

You could use [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
Date.strptime('2018-W53', '%Y-W%W')
#=> #<Date: 2018-12-31 ((2458484j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Note that `%W` and `%V` (commercial week) are defined differently and produce different results.

`%W` is defined as:

> The week 1 of YYYY starts with a Monday. The days in the year before the first week are in week 0.

`%V` is defined as:

> The week 1 of YYYY starts with a Monday and includes YYYY-01-04.
>   The days in the year before the first week are in the last week of
>   the previous year.

Some examples:

```
Date.new(2018,  1,  1).strftime('%Y-W%W / %G-CW%V') #=> "2018-W01 / 2018-CW01"
Date.new(2018, 12, 31).strftime('%Y-W%W / %G-CW%V') #=> "2018-W53 / 2019-CW01"

Date.new(2019,  1,  1).strftime('%Y-W%W / %G-CW%V') #=> "2019-W00 / 2019-CW01"
Date.new(2019, 12, 31).strftime('%Y-W%W / %G-CW%V') #=> "2019-W52 / 2020-CW01"

Date.new(2020,  1,  1).strftime('%Y-W%W / %G-CW%V') #=> "2020-W00 / 2020-CW01"
Date.new(2020, 12, 31).strftime('%Y-W%W / %G-CW%V') #=> "2020-W52 / 2020-CW53"

Date.new(2021,  1,  1).strftime('%Y-W%W / %G-CW%V') #=> "2021-W00 / 2020-CW53"
Date.new(2021, 12, 31).strftime('%Y-W%W / %G-CW%V') #=> "2021-W52 / 2021-CW52"
```

Comment: OP, Stefan and I seem to be giving you contradictory answers. We are not. You have to pick a date system and stick to it. Use my answer if you pick commercial. Use Stefan's if you're going to use civil. And don't mix them. :)

Comment: Thank you @Stefan

Answer (score 4):

From API docs:

> the first calendar week of the year is the one that includes the first Thursday of that year. In the Gregorian calendar, this is equivalent to the week which includes January 4.

Thus, 2018 *doesn't* have 53 weeks. The last day of the last week of 2018 is:

```
Date.commercial(2018, 52, 7)
# => #<Date: 2018-12-30 ((2458483j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

followed by the first week of 2019:

```
Date.commercial(2019, 1, 1)
# => #<Date: 2018-12-31 ((2458484j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

You seem to be working under the premise that 2018-12-31 is in 2018. It is not, not in Commercial date. If you're going to use the commercial year instead of the calendar year, use `%G`, not `%Y`, to get the commercial year, and `%V` for the week instead of `%W`.

```
date2018_12_31 = Date.commercial(2019, 1, 1)
date2018_12_31.strftime("%Y %W")                  # WRONG
# => "2018 53"
date2018_12_31.strftime("%G %V")                  # CORRECT
# => "2019 01"
```